# LDA as the dimension reduction before or after partitioning

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, classification

I am doing a classification and I have this question about using LDA just for dimension reduction:

Shall the LDA be applied on whole feature matrix including train and test data and then (after reducing the dimension of data) do the partitioning of feature matrix to provide train and test sets for classification? Is it true?

Then, suppose we need to partition the data before applying the LDA. **How is it possible to do the classification on the test data using the Matlab's internal classifiers like kNN and SVM?**

Answer (score 3):

You should generate the LDA on the train and afterwards apply it on the test set as well.

The reason is that you wan't to check how your entire processing chain performs on unseen data. If you generate the LDA model on train/test it might be that otherwise less important information might disappear.

Actually if you determine the number of dimensions you should go for a train/test/validation split. Where you determine the optimal number of dimension on train/test. Then build LDA+Model on train and test merged and evaluate on validation.

Comment: Thanks @CAFEBABE. I use the Matlab internal SVM and KNN; so, how I can separate the data into train and test and after finding the projection matrix using LDA on the train data and then apply that matrix to the test data? I mean how can I do this approach using the Matlab internal Classifiers? Can you help please?

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm not familiar with Matlab. However this should help you "After training a ClassificationDiscriminant model object by using fitcdiscr, use the function predict and the trained model object to generate C code that predicts labels for new data. For details, see Code Generation." so basically do a fitcdiscr on train. Evalutate on test using predict https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcdiscr.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#outputarg_Mdl